Decoupling cap powered via ground return?
I have a new 4 layer board (Pwr/Sig, GND, GND, Pwr/Sig) that is behaving in a way I don't understand and some how "back powering" a 5v plane it shouldn't be able to.
The board is in 2 sections.  One section is power, a 24v buck to 5v/3.3v regulator and an Ethernet chip and the second section the 24v supply to a pair of op-amps for 0-10v outputs.
The 24v supply is a single wide trace on layer 4 that supplies both sections (Buck & Op-Amps).
There was a silly error in my buck layout, so I wanted to continue to test the Op-Amp part of the board by injecting a voltage into the op-amp section.
So I physically cut the 24v rail and removed a chunk of the copper trace. I then soldered a feed onto a de-coupling cap that supplies the 24v to the 2 op-amps. The only power planes in that section of the board is a GND plane.
With a small test voltage supplied only to that capacitor, the 2 op-amps both see the voltage as expected, however, so does my 5v power plane in the other part of the board as does the 3v3 regulator and power section.
To my mind this should be physically impossible, the 24v trace has been physically cut & 2-3mm removed between the op-amps and buck converter sections. There should be no way that injecting power in that part of the board should supply the 3v3 regulator and power section, yet there it is.
The interesting thing is the 5v plane doesn't power up immediately, as if the 470uF capacitor in the power section is charging up.  With 5v on the op-amps, it climbs to 4.45v after a minute or so then drops back to slowly 0v as I read it.

The 24v buck has been physically removed from the board and this
470uF cap is only connected to 5v and GND.
Nothing is connected to
the 5v rail.
The PSU shows no load on the circuit.
My DMM says there
is no continuity between the 2 sections and shows a 1.3M Ohm
resistance between the 2 points.
The traces are all external as is
the 5v plane and they all look good.

Could this cap be back powering itself from the GND signal that it shares with the op-amps? Is that even a thing?!
Otherwise, I'm baffled...
Edit: added schematic. The op-amp signals go straight to header pins.


Please post a schematic of how the op-amp side of the board is connected to the other side of the board. Is it just the 24V power rail, or are there analogue or digital signals connecting the two together? Most likely there is some signal connecting the two which is back-feeding power via ESD protection diodes in e.g. the ethernet chip.

1.3MOhm is not the same as no continuity. Clearly there is something connecting the two halves which is allowing power to bleed through.
